# Which are the non-WP equivalents to HTC's Windows Phone range?

Tags: android, htc

I'm assuming that HTC's Windows Phone devices (e.g. Titan, Radar) have not been designed from scratch for WP7, and that HTC manufacture equivalent Android phones with the same casing, dimensions, and some shared hardware.

How can I figure out which are the Android equivalents to the HTC Radar and HTC Titan?

Reason for asking is that for repairs, reviews, diagnostics (e.g. YouTube videos showing how to replace a screen or similar) etc it's useful to be able to search online beyond just the Windows Phone brandname (which can have pretty limited results, at the moment).

Assuming, as I say, there are hardware equivalents in the Android universe.

Comment: Well, the HD2 (WM6.5) is ridiculously similar to the HD7 (WP7) and the Desire (android), but they are different product lines.

Comment: I think most of the newer phones have no android equivalents. Even though the form factor might look similiar, but most of the newer androids have dual core. What exactly are you trying to do with the phone?

Comment: FYI, I feel like this is borderline off topic. You may have better luck on the Android.Stackexchange site. I will leave this open for now, and wait to see what the community thinks about it.

Comment: @Joe I just feel that it's a WP7 problem for us WP7 users. we have this smaller ecosystem and a lot of the reviews and advice out there that deals with HTC devices may well apply to us if only we knew which basic WP7 equivalent handset type they're talking about

Comment: That is why I said "borderline" from a certain angle you are right, but on the other side if you showed a picture of the Radar to an Android power user, he might be able to tell you what the equivalent is. There might be some WP7 user that knows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTC HD2, HD7 and Desire HD are roughly equivalent.

The HTC Titan and Sensation XL are also roughly equivalent. I haven't heard of a Sensation XL 2 with a 16MP Camera though.

In both cases, the CPUs are the same, as is most of the hardware, but while the WP version has 512MB RAM, the Android version has 768MB RAM.

The Radar, Surround, Mozart and 7 Pro don't have any direct equivalents.

Comment: I think you mean Desire HD

Comment: right you are! edited